# How to hide a form while we move to next form in Winforms?

Tags: winforms

I created few Forms while running this project I need to hide the 1st Form while I call the second Form from first Form button on runtime. I tried this code `**Login.ActiveForm.Hide();**` but it showing error like **Object reference not set to instance of object**.

I need to hide that From1 while clicking button on Form1 & move onto second Form2 now If I click button on Form2 I need to show that hidden Form1.

Help me to complete this task.

Thanks in advance. Srihari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the next form (presuming it is not opened as a `.ShowDialog()`) then you can call `this.Hide();` to hide the first form.

In the button click event on form2 you can traverse the OpenForms collection and reshow form1.

An example being:

```
foreach ( Form openForm in Application.OpenForms ) {
   if ( openForm.GetType ( ) == typeof ( Form1 ) ) {
       openForm.Show();
   }
}
```